# Wordpress - How to write simple query on wordpress ?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I am a newbie and currently learning wordpress , i am struggling to write a query in wordpress. I have written it something like this but seesm like its coming null.

```
 $querystr = "SELECT * 
                FROM $wpdb->seeker_saved_mark_job ";
 $movie_names = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
            var_dump($movies_names);
```

The `seeker_saved_mark_job` is placed in meta table. I want to get all the results from this table, and they do exist but Its coming null

Comment: In which mate table? postmeta or other

Comment: Its postmeta table sir

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
global $wpdb;
$querystr = "SELECT * FROM  ".$wpdb->base_prefix."postmeta WHERE `meta_key`='seeker_saved_mark_job'";
$movie_names = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
var_dump($movies_names);
```